# Exporting a form to a CSV file does not work in WordPress but it does in PHP

Tags: forms, export, csv

I have a form with some fields that I need to implement in a WordPress template. If I do it in vanilla PHP it works but when I put it in a WordPress template it doesn't work, can it be a problem with `$_POST`?

```php
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Telesales
 */
?>

<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $DOFMonth = $_POST['DOFMonth'];
    $DOFDay = $_POST['DOFDay'];
    $DOFYear = $_POST['DOFYear'];

    
   

        $Content = "Name,LastName,Birthday\n";
        $Content .= "$firstName,$lastName,$DOFMonth-$DOFDay-$DOFYear\n";

        $FileName = $firstName."-".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";
        header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"'); 
        echo $Content;
        exit();
    
} ?>

<form action="" method="post">

  <label>First name</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Rose" required="" value="">
  <br>

  <label>Last name</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="McDonnell" required="" value="">
  <br>

  <label>Date of Birth</label>
  <select name="DOFMonth" required="">
    <option value="null">Month</option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
  </select>

  <select name="DOFDay" required="">
    <option value="null">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <select name="DOFYear" required="">
    <option value="null">Year</option>
    <option value="1920">1920</option>

  </select>


  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: if it doesn't do what you expected it to do, what did it do instead? How is it broken? Empty CSV?

Comment: No, it simply does nothing. But if I do it in a separate PHP outside of Wordpress it works perfectly.

Comment: I suspect the problem is the closing PHP tag followed by blank space and newlines, then an opening PHP tag. The moment you output anything even if it's blank spaces PHP will send HTTP headers telling the browser to expect a webpage. Now it's too late to call `header` to send a CSV, because HTTP headers can only be sent once. You should be seeing this as a series of PHP warnings and PHP notices in your PHP error log

Comment: Also there's lots of if statements checking `$error` but this variable is never used anywhere, there is no error checking code

Comment: I have removed the error checking. And all references to $error. Now it does output the content but if I remove the headers I won't be able to download the .csv, right?

Comment: No no no you've misunderstood, I never said to remove the `header` calls! What I'm saying is that you can only send HTTP headers once, and the moment you send any type of output PHP will send the headers for you, and that's exactly what you've done here by closing your PHP tags, outputting 2 newlines, then opening them again.  Those newlines are HTML content, so PHP tells the browser to expect HTML, sends the headers, and then starts sending HTML. This means when your code calls `header` to tell it to expect a Excel/CSV file it's too late! Headers have already been sent!

Comment: This is why constantly opening and closing PHP tags can be problematic because it's not just HTML tags, spaces and newlines matter too. The fix is super easy, don't send output before you call `header`, remove the useless closing PHP tag and opening PHP tag just after your comment, _then go find your PHP error log so that if this happens again it becomes obvious rather than it being a surprise_

Comment: Trying to avoid the issues that @Tom J Nowell highlighted here is why I've completely switched to generating any CSVs via AJAX.  It allows me to completely encapsulate the CSV building function and I just trigger it via a JS function.  Prior to that I was constantly combatting weird behaviors (of my own doing) in the output.  Highly, highly recommend you try that route.

Comment: You can recreate this issue by creating a working CSV download form then inserting this just before the CSV generation code: `?>   <?php`